# Scope import for an instance only

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, scope, singleton

Good evening to everyone.

I'm not sure how can I explain my issue. I will show it to you by showing examples of the code and expected results. I could not use code from the real issue because the code is under license. I am very sorry for that and I will be glad of someone can help me solve my issue.

I'm using latest version of `webpack`, `babel`.

My application is spliced to three parts what are dynamically imported by each other. It is mean if I run split chunks plugin it will really create three clear files.

The parts are `Core`, `Shared`, `Application`. Where the `Core` only creating an instance of the application.

Result of the parts is bundled to single file. So it is linked by one html's script tag.

Project structure is:

```
src/app    // For Application
src/core   // For Core
src/shared // For Shared
```

In webpack configuration I am resolving alias for import ˙Editor$˙.
I renamed naming of variables because they are including project name.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "Editor$": path.resolve('./src/app/statics/Editor.js'),
    }
},
```

The content of Core file is

```
function createInstance(name, id) {
    import("app").then(App => {
        App(name, id)
    });
}
```

The little bit of Application file is

```
imports...
import Framework from "./framework"
function createApp(name, id) {
    new Framework({name, id}).$mount(...)
}

export default createApp
```

In the Application classes (what are instantiated inside Framework)
Is this import

```
import Editor from "Editor"
```

The Editor class is a singleton. But only for created instance.

```
class Editor {
    static instance;

    id = null;

    constructor(){
        if(this.constructor.instance){
            return this.constructor.instance
        }

        this.constructor.instance = this
    }

    static get Instance() {
        return this.instance || (this.instance = new this())
    }

    static get Id {
        return this.Instance.id;
    }

}

export default Editor
```

The issue is webpack dependency resolving. Because webpack puts and unify all imports to the top of the file.

So the imports are evaluated once through the life-cycle of the program.

But I need to tell webpack something like: There is an instance creation. Declare the new Editor singleton for this scope. Don not use the already cached one.

My another idea how to fix this is to set context for the instance. And in the Editor singleton create something like `new Map<Context, Editor>` if you get what I mean. But I did not find a way how to set a context for an instance or scope the import only for it.

I will appreciate any help. I am googling two days and still no have idea how to do it without rewriting all the imports.

Sorry for bugs in my English. I am not native speaker and my brain is not for languages.

Thanks everyone who take look into my issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about recreating the Editor:

```
  // Editor.js
  class Editor {
   // ...
  }

  let instance;

 export function scope(cb) {
     instance = new Editor();
     cb();
     instance = null;
 }

 export default function createEditor() { 
    if(!instance) throw Error("Editor created out of scope!");
    return instance;
 }
```

That way you can easily set up different scopes:

```
 // index.js
 import {scope} from "./editor";

 scope(() => {
    require("A");
    require("B");
 });

 scope(() => {
   require("C");
 });

 // A
 import Editor from "./editor";
 (new Editor()).sth = 1;

  // B
 import Editor from "./editor";
 console.log((new Editor()).sth); // 1

 // C
 import Editor from "./editor";
 console.log((new Editor()).sth); // undefined

 // note that this will fail:
 setTimeout(() => {
   new Editor(); // error: Editor created out of scope
 }, 0);
```

That also works for nested `require`s and `import`s as long as they are not dynamic.

Comment: Hello, thank you for quick answer.

I'm resolving modules by `import` syntax instead of `require`.
Because all classes are written in EcmaScript 6 and has default export.

Let me show you an one class of them:

`
import Editor from "Editor"

class Blot extends ... {
    onCreate() {
        Editor.Something.Do.That("something")
    }
}
`
Using your idea I have to rewrite all these class to support the "syntax" change.

The Editor is created inside Core and is keep alive until page is refreshed.
I' m trying to find a way without editing these all files.

Comment: Anyway I like your solution if I a little bit modify it but I'm interested in solution through webpack. If I would tell him to do something like memory barricade. Do not reuse the variable but create the new at the place.

Comment: Would be great If I could wrap the `createApp(name, id)` to something like context. And everything inside it could access it like `context.id`, `context.etc`.

Comment: @siOnzee yes, that is possible but complicated. Edited to fit your exact usecase

Comment: Well, reason why I'm doing this is because of support multiple running editors. Because all is imported once and of the top of all. Then the variable `instance` will be replaced in the next one created instance and the first one editor will stop working.

Comment: You said `yes, that is possible but complicated`. Do you have any resource or idea where to find it? What is the terminology of it?

Because this solution sounds better and I would use it in another projects and to experience myself.